# Will I benefit from SQL Server 2014 In-Memory tables if my tables are already fully cached in-memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

Our most frequently used database is relatively small (5GB), and as a consequence, our 16GB memory dedicated SQL Server 2012 database server chooses to cache all used tables in memory (Buffer Cache Hit Ratio is 100% constantly). Some people in our team want to move to SQL Server 2014 to increase performance with In-Memory Tables, however I'm not convinced that doing such will increase performance since our tables are **already** in memory.

Is there more to the new In-Memory Tables in SQL Server 2014, or in my scenario there is indeed little to gain?

Comment: In-Memory Tables are for very specific needs. If you are having performance issues on a 5GB database you need to look at your queries and table design.

Comment: Which is exactly what my suggestion would be instead. There are so many ways to optimize our system, but people seem to want to chase new fancy technologies because they're advertised to "increase performance 20 times".

Comment: Have a look at this post - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-promise-and-the-pitfalls-of-in-memory-oltp/

Comment: You start with the problem queries.     Again, in-memory tables are for very specific needs.  I cannot help you with what people want to chase.

Comment: In-Memory OLTP is designed to scale workloads that are highly concurrent and/or write-intensive.

There are lots of things to know about it before wandering blindly down that path. My blog has many posts about the ups/downs of deploying this feature, which impacts many areas of the database environment.

Comment: Have you done *any* performance monitoring?  Do you know if there is blocking happening?  I'd bet that if you have blocking, and you can alleviate that issue, you may very well see huge improvements in perceived speed.  How do you know what's wrong, if you aren't monitoring performance at every level of the application?

Comment: Also don't go to SQL 2014, if you can help it.  SQL 2016 is an easier transition, has significantly better functionality, is a more long-lived platform.

Comment: Yes, there is much more to in-memory than just ensuring data are memory resident. As to whether or not moving to in-memory will improve performance depends much on your workload.

Comment: @Paparazzi: may want to consider adding a few bullets/examples of the specific needs addressed by in-memory tables; alternatively, provide a link to a more detailed discussion of the benefits of in-memory tables

Comment: I upvoted Max Vernon comment. In-memory **OLTP** is called OLTP because it was aimed to get rid of blocking, not just simply leave the data in memory. Also, don't think that all your structures can be migrated without refactoring, indexes are not the same that you get used to see in your on-disk storage, there are plenty of limitations, you can see them here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some people in our team want to move to SQL Server 2014 to increase performance with In-Memory Tables ...

That entirely depends on:

1. If more performance is needed
2. What the current bottleneck is

> however I'm not convinced that doing such will increase performance since our tables are already in memory.

You should be suspect that it may or may not improve performance, however the reason **isn't** because the data is already in memory. It is [mainly due](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2015/12/10/speeding-up-transactions-with-in-memory-oltp-in-sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database/) to being lock and latch free and less code execution with native compilation.

Thus, if your bottleneck isn't around locks or latches... the actual gain you receive will be minimal to none. This can be exacerbated if the actual bottleneck is the client.

There is a [great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/overview-and-usage-scenarios) about use cases for IMOLTP, and while we are at it you may want to look at 2016 and the uses of IMOLTP for advanced real time analytics.

> Is there more to the new In-Memory Tables in SQL Server 2014, or in my scenario there is indeed little to gain?

In-Memory objects (in this case, tables) are not just pinning data into memory. They have entirely different [memory structures and are lock and latch free](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673538.aspx).

There are additional differences in how the data is stored, how it affects database startup, etc.